# How to implement setInterval to update a clock every second?

Tags: jquery, date, time

I'm using the following code to display the current time on my website.

```
let currentDateTime = new Date();

hours = ('0'+currentDateTime.getHours()).slice(-2);
mins = ('0'+currentDateTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

let formattedTime = hours + ":" + mins;

$('#time').html(formattedTime);
```

This generates the time. However; the time is not running. I was hoping to make this clock run by setting an interval to update the time every second. I've tried adding `.setInterval(1000);` as follows:

```
let currentDateTime = new Date();

hours = ('0'+currentDateTime.getHours()).slice(-2);
mins = ('0'+currentDateTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

let formattedTime = hours + ":" + mins;

$('#time').html(formattedTime).setInterval(1000);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't make the time tick, and leaves me wondering why. I wish to learn what it is that I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is updateTime?

Comment: 1) `setInterval()` isn't a jQuery method. 2) `setInterval()` requires a callback function. I recommend you study the documentation carefully ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: My apologies Phil, I'm quite a rookie and was not aware of this. I appreciate you educating me, and will have a read.

Comment: Hello, look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your code in a function and then call it every seconde with setInterval

```js
function updateTime () {
  let currentDateTime = new Date();

  hours = ('0'+currentDateTime.getHours()).slice(-2);
  mins = ('0'+currentDateTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

  let formattedTime = hours + ":" + mins;

  $('#time').html(formattedTime)
}

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// HTML element where the time will be displayed
var clock = $('#clock');

// Returns an object with the time, minutes and seconds
function time() {
  // Object Instance Date
  var date = new Date();
  return {
    hours: date.getHours(),
    minutes: date.getMinutes(),
    seconds: date.getSeconds(),
  }
}

// Execute the time function every second
setInterval(function() {
  // We store the object that returns the time function
  var date = time();
  // We use the .text method to display the time
  clock.text(date.hours + ':' + date.minutes + ':' + date.seconds)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="clock"></h1>
```

Comment: You're missing the zero-padding on the numbers